# unable to connect to mongo in instance

Tags: mongodb

[image]

I am unable to connect to mongo its show the below error

Answer (score 1):

Check that `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`, there is error message what tells what went wrong.

BTW, please don't insert screen captures. Just copy&paste lines and tag text as "code sample"

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

kill the pid of running mongoDB instance

```
ps -ef | grep mongo
```

get the pid from console

```
kill -9 pidNumber
```

then type on the console

```
start mongodb
```

In case it wont work

delete the value from mongo.lock and save it and then run `start mongodb` it will run